# Is there a way to load an object before DOM is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The way I currently try to work around this is to get the object loaded on `$(document).ready()`. And run the rest of the scripts with `$(window).load()` . However I am still ending up adding a 0.5 sec delay to make sure that the object loads completely as it is retrieving data from 2 ajax calls.

Is there a better way of loading an object before DOM loads or at the same time but only when it is done loading the object and getting the data, and then call the rest of the functions?

```
document.ready =  function (){
object.initall();   
};
```

the `initall()` function calls the two methods which get data from 2 different services.

```
window.onload = function () {
setTimeout(function(){
    object.loadEventTable();
    object.loadChart();     
    $('#uid').text(object.lData.header.uid);        
},500);
};
```

Comment: The dom doesn't need to be loaded for anything, all it does is ensure that the callback is run after the initial document has been parsed. If `.initall` doesn't try to select elements in the document, it doesn't matter if the document is ready

Comment: Thank you all for your responses ... it actually gave me a good idea on how to work around this. yey!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can make it a function and  put function call at the beginning section of your page. May be at the opening of your body tag

```
object.loadEventTable();
object.loadChart();     
window.onload = function () {
setTimeout(function(){   
    $('#uid').text(object.lData.header.uid);        
},500);
};
```

Comment: Adding the a function and call it at the beginning, would make the $("#uid").text fail..

Comment: This is kind of how I solved it except $("#uid") was moved to another function as a call back. That function is actually loading the content and as a call back i set it to the proper UID. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to generate the 'response' server side and put it into your code directly, so a separate call is not necessary.